# Can't open pdf files in phonegap app

Tags: cordova, download, external, google-docs, pdf-viewer

In my phonegap built mobile app I am using Google doc viewer for viewing PDF files from external sites.With this some files are loading but some not,especially files with size greater than 3MB.How can I solve this? Is there any alternative PDF viewer is available for phonegap? Or how can i download external PDF files through phonegap?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using window.open('http://demo.com/test.pdf','_system','location=no')